# Unity UI Button has insane transition state behaviour - it remains highlighted after being clicked

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

It took me a while to figure out the problem with Unity UI Button Transition:

**Problem:**
I hover on the button object, it goes to highlighted state, that's Fine. If I press mouse on button and it goes to pressed state then I move mouse outside of button so its no longer over button. The button goes to highlighted state instead of normal state. I need to click in empty space to get the normal state of button.

**TLDR:**

[image]

Comment: That seems like designed behaviour - with interactive UI elements (for example, you can see this with HTML buttons and links), a clicked element will often retain "focus" after the initial interaction. Clicking away here will clear the focus, which is why the button is no longer highlighted when you do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for a Button element in Unity - it retains focus after the initial interaction, causing it to show the Highlighted Color. Clicking away clears the focus, so it no longer becomes highlighted then.

To change this behaviour, you can switch the **Navigation** setting.

[image]

Currently, it's set to *Automatic*. According to [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-SelectableNavigation.html), the option you want to use instead is *None*, which results in:

> No keyboard navigation. Also ensures that it does not receive focus from clicking/tapping on it.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I don't see how this is intuitive behaviour in mouse interaction. But as long as they have an option to avoid this I am good to go. Thanks @Serlite

Answer (score 3):

To retain keyboard automatic navigation, you probably want to inherit from IPointerExitHandler and deselect on exit:

```
public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData data)
{
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
}
```

You could add checks to only deselect `gameObject` if already selected.

Comment: @UmairM: The accepted answer doesn't allow navigation, which I needed for gamepad support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use keyboard navigation and also get rid of this problem you can add this function to update:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use navigation in any way you want to, it gives you full control on how you want to do the transition, so you don't need such workaround. Plus this solution would affect game performance and might introduce more bugs depending on your other input behaviours in the game.

Comment: If you make navigation is none you are unable to use keyboard navigation

Comment: Yes! but to use keyboard navigation you can set the navigation to manual and edit clicking on visualize button. That's what I meant by full control.

Comment: You mean I must change the navigation to explicit and assign change "Select On Up","Select On Down", "Select On Right" and "Select On Left" for each button?